# about python __doc__ docstring

Tags: python, doc, docstring

i want to show docstring of my function,
but if i use like this

```
@cost_time
def func():
    "define ...."
    blabla
print func.__doc__
```

it will not show the docstring,just because i use some meta programming tricky,
how can fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your wrapped function returned from the `cost_time` decorator must have the docstring instead of `func`. Therefore, use [`functools.wraps`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) which correctly sets `__name__` and `__doc__`:

```
from functools import wraps

def cost_time(fn):
    @wraps(fn)
    def wrapper():
        return fn()

    return wrapper
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`functools.wraps()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).