# How to print docstring outside a function using wrappers?

Tags: python, decorator, docstring, python-decorators

Quite related to [about python __doc__ docstring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865254/about-python-doc-docstring).
In case I don't use functools and use the wrapper as mentioned in [How to print Docstring of python function from inside the function itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8822701/how-to-print-docstring-of-python-function-from-inside-the-function-itself), is there a way to get the docstring printed.

```
def passmein(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(func, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@passmein
def testfunc(me):
    """This is a test function"""
    #print me.__doc__

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print testfunc.__doc__
```

This returns none.

Comment: Why are you trying to print `me.__doc__` instead of `testfunc.__doc__`?

Comment: Meanwhile, if all you're asking is how to wrap functions in a way that preserves the docstring without using `functools.wraps`… just look at [the source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/functools.py#l15) and do the same thing. But I can't imagine why you'd ever want that.

Comment: @abamert- The print was to use it to display the docstring from inside the function when I call it.

Comment: So why are you trying to print the docstring of its first parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would not want to use `functools.wraps`, but you could add the doc string to `wrapper` yourself:

```
def passmein(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    return wrapper

@passmein
def testfunc(me):
    """This is a test function"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print testfunc.__doc__
```

Comment: Ah! Thanks. This helps me understand wrappers better.